# Merging 2 shaders

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

I am currently using 2017.3.0f.3. I have two CG shaders that I would like to merge into a single shader. One is for handling the distortion of a sprite (like waves/wind), the other keeps it facing the camera (billboard). They work independently but I need them to work together.

Shader 1:

```
Shader "Cg  shader for billboards" {
   Properties {
      _MainTex ("Texture Image", 2D) = "white" {}
      _ScaleX ("Scale X", Float) = 1.0
      _ScaleY ("Scale Y", Float) = 1.0
   }
   SubShader {
      Pass {   
         CGPROGRAM

         #pragma vertex vert  
         #pragma fragment frag

         // User-specified uniforms            
         uniform sampler2D _MainTex;        
         uniform float _ScaleX;
         uniform float _ScaleY;

         struct vertexInput {
            float4 vertex : POSITION;
            float4 tex : TEXCOORD0;
         };
         struct vertexOutput {
            float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
            float4 tex : TEXCOORD0;
         };

         vertexOutput vert(vertexInput input) 
         {
            vertexOutput output;

            output.pos = mul(UNITY_MATRIX_P, 
              mul(UNITY_MATRIX_MV, float4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0))
              + float4(input.vertex.x, input.vertex.y, 0.0, 0.0)
              * float4(_ScaleX, _ScaleY, 1.0, 1.0));

            output.tex = input.tex;

            return output;
         }

         float4 frag(vertexOutput input) : COLOR
         {
            return tex2D(_MainTex, float2(input.tex.xy));   
         }

         ENDCG
      }
   }
}
```

Shader 2:

```
Shader "Transparent/Cutout/Diffuse Shake" {

    Properties {
        _Color ("Main Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
        _MainTex ("Base (RGB) Trans (A)", 2D) = "white" {}
        _Cutoff ("Alpha cutoff", Range(0,1)) = 0.5
        _ShakeDisplacement ("Displacement", Range (0, 1.0)) = 1.0
        _ShakeTime ("Shake Time", Range (0, 1.0)) = 1.0
        _ShakeWindspeed ("Shake Windspeed", Range (0, 1.0)) = 1.0
        _ShakeBending ("Shake Bending", Range (0, 1.0)) = 1.0
    }

    SubShader {
        Tags {"Queue"="AlphaTest" "IgnoreProjector"="True" "RenderType"="TransparentCutout"}
        LOD 200

    CGPROGRAM
    #pragma target 3.0
    #pragma surface surf Lambert alphatest:_Cutoff vertex:vert addshadow

    sampler2D _MainTex;
    fixed4 _Color;
    float _ShakeDisplacement;
    float _ShakeTime;
    float _ShakeWindspeed;
    float _ShakeBending;

    struct Input {
        float2 uv_MainTex;
    };

    void FastSinCos (float4 val, out float4 s, out float4 c) {
        val = val * 6.408849 - 3.1415927;
        float4 r5 = val * val;
        float4 r6 = r5 * r5;
        float4 r7 = r6 * r5;
        float4 r8 = r6 * r5;
        float4 r1 = r5 * val;
        float4 r2 = r1 * r5;
        float4 r3 = r2 * r5;
        float4 sin7 = {1, -0.16161616, 0.0083333, -0.00019841} ;
        float4 cos8  = {-0.5, 0.041666666, -0.0013888889, 0.000024801587} ;
        s =  val + r1 * sin7.y + r2 * sin7.z + r3 * sin7.w;
        c = 1 + r5 * cos8.x + r6 * cos8.y + r7 * cos8.z + r8 * cos8.w;
    }


    void vert (inout appdata_full v) {

        float factor = (1 - _ShakeDisplacement -  v.color.r) * 0.5;

        const float _WindSpeed  = (_ShakeWindspeed  +  v.color.g );    
        const float _WaveScale = _ShakeDisplacement;

        const float4 _waveXSize = float4(0.048, 0.06, 0.24, 0.096);
        const float4 _waveZSize = float4 (0.024, .08, 0.08, 0.2);
        const float4 waveSpeed = float4 (1.2, 2, 1.6, 4.8);

        float4 _waveXmove = float4(0.024, 0.04, -0.12, 0.096);
        float4 _waveZmove = float4 (0.006, .02, -0.02, 0.1);

        float4 waves;
        waves = v.vertex.x * _waveXSize;
        waves += v.vertex.z * _waveZSize;

        waves += _Time.x * (1 - _ShakeTime * 2 - v.color.b ) * waveSpeed *_WindSpeed;

        float4 s, c;
        waves = frac (waves);
        FastSinCos (waves, s,c);

        float waveAmount = v.texcoord.y * (v.color.a + _ShakeBending);
        s *= waveAmount;

        s *= normalize (waveSpeed);

        s = s * s;
        float fade = dot (s, 1.3);
        s = s * s;
        float3 waveMove = float3 (0,0,0);
        waveMove.x = dot (s, _waveXmove);
        waveMove.z = dot (s, _waveZmove);
        v.vertex.xz -= mul ((float3x3)_World2Object, waveMove).xz;

    }

    void surf (Input IN, inout SurfaceOutput o) {
        fixed4 c = tex2D(_MainTex, IN.uv_MainTex) * _Color;
        o.Albedo = c.rgb;
        o.Alpha = c.a;
    }
    ENDCG
    }

    Fallback "Transparent/Cutout/VertexLit"
}
```

I have tried a failed multiple times already. Is it possible?

Comment: This can be done, but you're going to need to do a lot of math and trial and error. Essentially your goal is to combine both `vert` functions into a single one (I'd suggest making the billboard part happen first). The problem is that one shader is a *surface* shader and the other is a *fragment* shader, and that gets tricky fast

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, and there's more than one way to go:

The simplest would be to not use the billboard shader at all and just orient the transform to look at the camera using a c# script. If you are not looking into efficiency, this is the best solution.

The other solution is to merge the wave function into the vertex shader of the billboard one. You just need to apply the wave distortion before the billboard transformation:

```
input.vertex.xz -= mul ((float3x3)_World2Object, waveMove).xz;
output.pos = mul(UNITY_MATRIX_P, 
          mul(UNITY_MATRIX_MV, float4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0))
          + float4(input.vertex.x, input.vertex.y, 0.0, 0.0)
          * float4(_ScaleX, _ScaleY, 1.0, 1.0));
```

(you ofc need to move everything related to waveMove along with it :) )

If you need the lighting to work (the benefit of using surface shader), then it gets trickier. Surface shaders transform into clip/screen space behind the scene, after the execution of your main vertex shader method. Since billboard transformation needs to break down that transformation things get messy: you need to transform the vertices into their final clip space position, and then convert it back into object space so it can be re-transformed again behind the scene into the desired position.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I am indeed trying to arrive at an efficient solution so I thought merging the shaders was the way to go. I don't need any lighting, just some computationally cheap approach to getting wavey and billboard seaweed/bushes. Shaders are not my area so I'm not aware of what can be chucked (e.g. from what you said perhaps I don't need to use a surface shader?)

Comment: If you are fine with just displaying the texture, "unlit" like the billboard shader does, than you should go for option 2.